# How is a dimension of an ideal defined in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose I consider the ring $R=\Bbb Z_2[x]/\langle x^9+1\rangle$

$x^9+1$ has a complete factorization into irreducible polynomials like

$x^9+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$

Now $I=\langle x+1\rangle /\langle x^9+1\rangle  $ is an ideal in  $R$

I got a question

> What is the dimension of $I$ in $R$?

Can someone please tell me how is a dimension of an ideal defined in $R$ and what will be the answer?

Comment: You’re asking us to guess how dimension is defined in your learning material in this context. At the very least, you should say what the learning material is to help with the guessing.

Comment: @rschwieb;Its a question in abstract algebra in our exam,and this the exact question provided,I dont know what it is so I asked if there is some standard notation for this

Comment: you should no tbe asking us question off your exam. You should be asking your teacher.

Comment: @rschwieb;It is a PhD qualifying exam,so I have no access to the teacher of the institutes

Comment: @rschwieb;Anyway do you have any answer for the question,because I think what we are talking is not going to help either of us

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help you definitively, but I'm sure someone will. Our conversation so far above is proving the need for you to **provide context**. First you provided only the question, then you incompletely told me it was on an exam, then you revised that to be working on a qual exam independently. If you had said that from the start, we'd know that situation and the context would be established.  Next time do that up front.

Comment: Is the exam available online where anyone can see it, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

A naïve interpretation of dimension in this case would be the $\mathbb Z_2$ dimension. In your case the original ring $R$ is $9$ dimensional over $\mathbb Z_2$, and $I$ has codimension $1$ in $R$ (since $(x-1)$ has codimension $1$ in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$.) So in that case it would be $8$ dimensional.

But dimension could also refer to the [Krull dimension of $R/I$](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_ideal). That seems rather dull though since proper quotients of a polynomial ring over a field are all Artinian, so that the Krull dimension is always $0$.

None of it seems related to the factorization you gave, and without more context it's hard to guess what was intended.